# Laravel automatic logout issue with filter

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-filters

I need some Filter to redirect user to the specific control panel like admin will go to he admin panel and writer will go to he writer area.. so i defined some filters
Without these filter user are not automatic logout but when using these filter user automatic log out and even navigation one page to second page user automatic logout.

is there any problem in my code?

Here is the code:

**Route**

```
Route::filter('allow_only_admin', function()    {
    if (Session::get('role') !== "admin" ){
        if (Session::get('role') == 'writer') {
            return Redirect::route('windex');
        }
    }   });

Route::filter('allow_only_writer', function()
{
    if (Session::get('role') !== "writer" ){
        if (Session::get('role') == 'admin') {
            return Redirect::route('orders.all');
        }
    }
});
Route::group(['prefix' => 'writer','before'=>'allow_only_writer'], function()
{
    Route::get('index', ['as' => 'windex', 'uses'   => 'Writer@showIndex']);
});
```

Comment: are you store users role on database ? I mean user role can access by User model

Comment: roles are not define in Users table... i am using https://github.com/romanbican/roles for roles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try something like this i didnt test this code

```
Route::filter('no_auth', function(){
        if(Auth::check()){
            if(!Auth::user()->is('admin')){
                return Redirect::route('routename');
            }

            if(!Auth::user()->is('writer')){
                return Redirect::route('routename');
            }

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
Route::filter('allow_only_admin', function(){
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role !== "admin" && Auth::user()->role == 'writer' ){
            return Redirect::route('windex');
    }
    return Redirect::route('home or somewhere');
});

Route::filter('allow_only_writer', function(){
    if (Auth::check() && Auth::user()->role !== "writer" &&  Auth::user()->role == 'admin'){
            return Redirect::route('orders.all');
    }
    return Redirect::route('home or somewhere');
});
```

**N.B** : if users can't have multiple roles then you don't want to check both `Auth::user()->role !== "admin" && Auth::user()->role == 'writer'`
only one is enough

```
Auth::user()->role == 'writer'
```

Comment: you're accessing a property `role` on an object `Auth::user()` which might not be instantiated (not logged in). This might result in errors. Within the if you might use `Auth::check()` or `Auth::user()`

Comment: @Luceos is it ok now ? I think you mean this

Comment: @tehc-sira this is not working in my case i don't have any role property in my users table i am using github.com/romanbican/roles for roles and there is a function for checking admin and returning true and false like this Auth::user()->is('admin');